# Ubuntu 13.10 change first weekday to Monday in calendar applet

Tags: 13.10, locale, calendar

Before the update (I was using 13.04), editing:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/locale
```

so that **LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"** does the job.

However in 13.10, this does not work anymore.

I've tried editing:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_AU
sudo gedit /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_GB
sudo gedit /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US
```

so that **first_weekday 2** in each of the files, but this also does not work.

As a reference, when I run `locale`, the output is

```
LANG=en_AU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_AU:en
LC_CTYPE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If LC_TIME is en_GB.UTF-8 in `/etc/default/locale`, and the `locale` command still states en_AU.UTF-8, you have user specific settings that override the system wide settings in `/etc/default/locale`.

Assuming that you live in Australia, and want regional format settings in general reflect what's typical in Australia, you can try to edit your `~/.profile` file and add this line:

`export LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8`